# protractor -- inject is not defined when testing angular services

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I'm writing a very simple test spec in protractor to get the gist of the framework. Everything worked fine until I tried to test services. Normally I'd call `inject` to get the dependency but now I get `inject is not defined` error. Here is the code of my test spec:

```
function SingleModelPage() {

    this.getDataList = function() {
        return element.all(by.repeater('d in data'));
    };

    this.get = function() {
        browser.get('http://localhost:8080/');
        element(by.css('#ln-single-model')).click();
    };
}

describe('Single Model Page', function() {
    var page = new SingleModelPage();
    var dataService;           

    beforeEach(function() {    
        page.get();            
    });     

    // I tried to add mock module but angular is not defined as well, so
    // I couldn't call angular.module
    beforeEach(inject(function(SingleModelDataService) {
        dataService = SingleModelDataService;
    }));  

    describe('Testing Setup', function() { 
        it('should load the single model page by default', function() {
            expect(page.getDataList().count()).toEqual(1);
        });
    });

    describe('Single Model Service', function() {
        it('should contain single model data service', function() {
            //expect(dataService).not.toEqual(null);
        });
    });   
});
```

Comment: did you ever find a fix for this? I'm looking through things now and I am starting to assume it is a fruitless cause.

Answer (score 4):

Generally protractor is designed for End to End testing. For testing services you should use karma.

Otherwise theoretically you can access your services like this:

```
browser.executeAsyncScript(function(callback) {
  var service = angular.injector(['MyModule']).get('myService');
  service.query({}, function(data) {
    callback(data);
  });
}).then(function (output) {
  console.log(output);
});
```

And there is an example:

https://github.com/andresdominguez/protractor-meetup/blob/master/test/e2e/api-helper.js

Answer (score 0):

That is because angular is not present in your namespace. 
Create a karma-require config for example with the "karma init" command.